# Multidex App not working on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-multidex

Recently I had to enable multidex support for our app as it failed to either install or crash on start on a number of devices running older versions of Android. After that was enabled the app managed to install, [with some tweaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522607/upgrading-to-fixed-version-of-app), on most Android versions except for 2.3.6 where it gives the following message:

> Cannot Download - The content is not supported on this phone

I am unable to test this as I don't have a device running 2.3.6 and also Android Studio does not provide an emulator for this version. I would appreciate if someone tells me what is going on with the app on Android 2.3.6 - i.e. why is not supported where as the app runs fine on other lower version like 2.3.3 and 2.2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is mentioned in the official page, where it could have problem before Android 4.0 (API level 14)

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations

Here are 2 main issues related to platform version

> Applications that use multidex may not start on devices that run
>   versions of the platform earlier than Android 4.0 (API level 14) due
>   to a Dalvik linearAlloc bug (Issue 22586). If you are targeting API
>   levels earlier than 14, make sure to perform testing with these
>   versions of the platform as your application can have issues at
>   startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded. Code
>   shrinking can reduce or possibly eliminate these potential issues.
>
> Applications using a multidex configuration that make very large
>   memory allocation requests may crash during run time due to a Dalvik
>   linearAlloc limit (Issue 78035). The allocation limit was increased in
>   Android 4.0 (API level 14), but apps may still run into this limit on
>   Android versions prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21).